# oracle database and users

Tags: database, oracle

Hi!

I'm just starting to learn about databases, oracle in general. I messed around in the Oracle SQL Developer and a very very basic question arose in my mind :)

In Oracle SQL Developer, you have to establish a connection (make a user) to connect to the database. The user then can hold tables, functions etc. Then, i can make more connections (users) to hold some other tables, functions etc.

So, here's my question: is the term 'user' the same as 'database'? Is each established connection (a user) a different database? Therefore, when it is said: "create a database connection", it means the same as "create a database"?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Connections in SQL Developer are distinct from Users.  That is, we can create several Connections for the same User; this is helpful as a way of having several different sessions for the same User.  Likewise we can create Users that cannot connect because they lack the CREATE SESSION privilege.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, a user is *[a user](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/user)* and a database is also referred to as a [*schema*](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/Schema). many different users can connect to the same schema (or to a different schema).

A schema contains tables, triggers, functions, procedures etc.

Comment: In Oracle, a database can contain many users, and the term schema refers to the objects owned by a user; thus, a single database can contain many schemas.  I recommend reading through the [Oracle Database Concepts](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28318/toc.htm) manual.  Share and enjoy.

Comment: @BobJarvis I should rephrase: when (many) people say "database" they actually refer to a schema. That's what I meant. BTW, a schema is owned by a user but can be accessed and modified by many users. Just like files in a file-system.

Comment: When people people say "database" meaning "schema" we know that they are familiar with MySQL or SQL Server, rather than Oracle.  Users do *not* connect to a schema.  Only the owner of a schema may modify its objects, unless they grant privileges on their objects to other users.  Your analogy with files in a filesystem is at best misleading.

Comment: @APC "Only the owner of a schema may modify its objects, unless they grant privileges on their objects to other users" - that's exactly the same with files.